# Is there any benefit in storing a function in a variable before assigning it to an event?

Tags: javascript

## 1

```
document.onkeydown = function(a) {
    //
};
```

## 2

```
var a = function(a) {
    //
};
document.onkeydown = a;
```

I had the idea that maybe in the first case, the function needs to be *re-parsed* (for lack of better word) every time the event happens, whereas in the second case it just points to the already *parsed* function.

If not this, maybe there is another (any) difference.

**Update**

If I understand this correctly, there is a difference between these, and it's better to use the second.

## 1

```
var a = window.onresize = function() {
    //
};
// ...
a();
```

## 2

```
var a = function() {
    //
};
window.onresize = a;
// ...
a();
```

Comment: Both ways are awful. Use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Are you going to reuse it?

Comment: @VisioN, question would still apply there too. :)

Comment: @epascarello That's another question :)

Comment: It has to be IE8 compatible, and I don't like the IE8 `addEventListener` equivalent, when this works just as well. It's not reused, but it could be.

Comment: There's never a "re-parsing" in your examples above. A function object is always passed by reference independently if it is anonymous or not. The only re-instantiation of the function object happens when the parser encounters a *Function Expression* more than once in the execution flow, a classic example being a function expression inside of a loop as in Joseph's answer. Of course, Function Declarations also generate more instantiations if you enter their execution context more than once (calling a function that has nested functions more than once).

Comment: Regarding your update: no, both forms are equivalent.

Comment: @bfavaretto: That's what I initially understood from the answer, that both `a` and `window.onresize` get their own copy of the function, rather than a pointer to it. Is it equivalent because both get the same function, which is already stored somewhere, so both only get a pointer to the same already stored function?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Thanks for your reply, but the later added function declarations and instantions part confused me more than it helped :)

Comment: Both get a pointer to the same function (think of the multiple  assignment right to left)

Comment: @bfavaretto: But how is this different from the loop in the answer, where different elements apparently get the same function as well, but not as a pointer but a copy?

Comment: In the loop, a new function is created on every iteration, because it's defined inside the loop block (for each value of `i` a new anonymous function is created).

Comment: @bfavaretto: Understood. Thanks. The interpreter cannot know (or doesn't care) that it already assigned the exact same function elsewhere, in a previous iteration of the loop.

Comment: Putting it in a layman's view: try to read the code line per line as the interpreter would. A `for` loop will repeat the lines inside its block multiple times. Each time the interpreter reaches a `function` keyword it will create a new function object. Then remember that objects are passed by reference and read your question's code - the interpreter will only hit `function` keywords once for each defined function.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Thanks. This is beyond the scope of this question now, but in the loop, would it be possible for a JS engine (like V8) to find out that an identical function was already assigned elsewhere, and optimise this away (at a lower level)?

Comment: Depends. On a low level as in generating a copy of the generated function instead of re-parsing is in the realm of possibilities. Though, it will never assign a reference to the function object created in a previous loop iteration as that'd simply break common logic.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Thanks, no further questions :)

Comment: Also, objects are only considered equal if they reference the same object, so you can do your own testing by trying `a === window.onresize` and you will see both of these point to the same function object. This is also one of the reasons Constructors and prototyping are commonly utilized. Also, a bit unrelated, but I've only got a good grasp on Function Declaractions vs Function Expression after reading [this article](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/), despite there are dozens of good results on google for those terms.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: You should submit your comments as answer.

Answer (score 4):

In your current form, there's no difference (the anonymous function might even be a *tad* faster). The only advantage of storing the function separately is when you do it in a loop (or if the function may have other uses).

---

For example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
    element[i].onkeydown = function () {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

every element will get its own copy of the function, which increases your page's memory usage.

If you instead store the function outside the loop:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var eventListener = function () {
    // whatever
};

for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
    element[i].onkeydown = eventListener;
}
```

they'll all share the same function.

---

**P.S.** As pointed out by @VisioN, a better way would be to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener). The same rules apply there too.

Comment: You can delete the `addEventListener` part, because it doesn't apply. I've also added a small follow-up question based on your reply.

Comment: @pdknsk - If you have another question, you should post it as another question. Don't just add on to your current question...

Comment: @JosephSilber move the `addEventListener` suggestion to the top, IMO :P